Question regarding enthalpy of sublimation vaporization and fusion
While learning Thermochemistry, I came across the formula

$\Delta H_{sub} = \Delta H_{vap} + \Delta H_{fus}$

Now my question is how that when we want to change the phase of a substance from solid to gas in sublimation, we have to go through 3 processes

Fusion of solid by providing heat equal to $\Delta H_{fus}$

Rising the temperature of a liquid from melting point to boiling point by providing heat equal to $n C dT$

Vaporization by providing heat equal to $\Delta H_{vap}$


Then should the formula not be > $\Delta H_{sub} = \Delta H_{vap} + \Delta H_{fus}+nC[T_{BP}-T_{MP}]$
Any help is welcome.

Be aware that  equality involving enthalpy changes like the above requires the same initial and final states, going via different paths, real or formal. Note that the respective phase change enthalpies are temperature dependent.

Lets do a Hess's Law examination of sublimation of some ice at a temperature below the freezing point:
First: Sublime the ice directly at T to vapor heat is supplied directly from the environment, think a gram of snow sitting on the ground.  ICE + heat of sublimation gives water vapor. This happens at temperature T.
Second Raise the temperature of the ice to zero Celsius: heat = [Cp of ice]delta T.
Melt the ice at zero Celsius: heat = Heat of fusion.
Evaporate the liquid at zero Celsius to vapor. Heat is heat of vaporization at zero Celsius. [Maintain pressure at VP at original T of the ice.] Since the water is of higher energy than the original ice the heat of vaporization is lower by the heat needed to raise the ice to water and the heat added in melting. As the temperature of a liquid is raised the heat of vaporization is lowered becoming zero at the critical temperature.
Finally lower the vapor T slowly at constant pressure to the initial temperature. Energy is [-Cp vapor] deltaT Result: one g less of ice one gram more of water vapor. Heat required is the heat of sublimation at the temperature of the ice. Sum the heats of each step to see what is involved in sublimation and evaporation.
Vapor pressure of a solid or liquid is a continuous function for each. There is a discontinuity at the melting-freezing point where the curves intersect. At the MP the vapor pressure of the liquid and solid are identical. Since both solid and liquid are confined to their volumes by the intermolecular bonds their chemical potentials remain constant and equal at the MP. When both phases are in equilibrium with each other and with vapor this is a constant temperature triple point that is maintained until one phase vanishes. A gas has no physical constraints so unless its chemical potential is constrained by a constant pressure there are no definitive boiling points.

Thanks for finding the misspellings. First I left out the word intrinsic. You added it in error. Gravity holds gases to the Earth and possibly in nebulae. that is extrinsic to the gases. Over the small distances and volumes under consideration Gravity is almost constant so gases fill the container and do not have an independent chemical potential; liquids and solids are much closer to independence. I gave a reasonably concise and accurate explanation of what is going on. As for tangents all I did was sublime some ice and try to give some insight into what is going on

I am not an astrophysicist, but it appears from what I've  read that a nebula can consist solely of gas unified by gravitational attraction. In any case, I did not understand the need for that last sentence among others. Also, in the Hess cycle you describe, what is the pressure in step 2?

What does this mean: "Vapor pressure of a solid or liquid is a continuous function for each." ? Continuous with respect to what?

"There is a discontinuity at the melting-freezing point where the curves intersect." Which curves are intersecting?

"When both phases are in equilibrium with each other and with vapor this is a constant temperature triple point that is maintained until one phase vanishes." You can have only one or two phases at the triple point. BTW you stated (or suggested?) that the chemical potential in a condensed phase is "intrinsic" (depending only on intermolecular forces).

When comparing the transitions it really helps to inspect a phase diagram such as that of water (this one adapted from a chemistry librext):

The blue arrows indicate transitions from solid to gas with identical initial (low) and final (high) temperatures $T_{low}$ and $T_{high}$, but pressure $p_\mathrm{1}$ lies below the triple point of water (point A in the diagram) and $p_\mathrm{2}$ above, so in transition 1 the solid sublimes whereas in 2 the solid is first converted to liquid and then gas.
We can then write the enthalpies associated with each process:
$$\Delta H_\textrm{1} = \int_\textrm{Tlow}^\textrm{Tsub} C_\textrm{p,s(p1)} dT + \Delta_\textrm{sub} H_\textrm{p1} + \int_\textrm{Tsub}^\textrm{Thigh} C_\textrm{p,g(p1)} dT \tag{1}$$
$$\Delta H_\textrm{2} = \int_\textrm{Tlow}^\textrm{Tm} C_\textrm{p,s(p2)} dT + \Delta_\textrm{m} H_\textrm{p2} + \int_\textrm{Tm}^\textrm{Tb} C_\textrm{p,l(p2)} dT + \Delta_\textrm{b} H_\textrm{p2} + \int_\textrm{Tb}^\textrm{Thigh} C_\textrm{p,g(p2)} dT \tag{2}$$
where e.g. $C_\textrm{p,s(p1)}$ indicates the temperature-dependent heat capacity of the solid at pressure $p_\textrm{1}$, $T_\textrm{sub}$ is the sublimation temperature at pressure $p_1$, and $T_\textrm{m}$ and $T_\textrm{b}$ are the melting and boiling temperatures at pressure $p_2$.
Inspecting the phase diagram of water we see that we might simplify things somewhat by choosing $T_{low}=T_\mathrm{sub}=T_\mathrm{m}$ and $T_{high}=T_\mathrm{b}$. This constrains $T_{low}$ to the red coexistence line below the triple point and $T_{high}$ to the red boiling curve above the triple point. As a result
$$\Delta H_\textrm{1} =  \Delta_\textrm{sub} H_\textrm{p1} + \int_\textrm{Tsub}^\textrm{Tb} C_\textrm{p,g(p1)} dT \tag{3}$$
$$\Delta H_\textrm{2} = \Delta_\textrm{m} H_\textrm{p2} + \int_\textrm{Tm}^\textrm{Tb} C_\textrm{p,l(p2)} dT + \Delta_\textrm{b} H_\textrm{p2}  \tag{4}$$
Now we can add two steps involving changes in pressure to link the end points of transitions 1 and 2:
$$\Delta H_\textrm{1} = \int_\textrm{p1}^\textrm{p2} V_s dp +  \Delta H_\textrm{2} + \int_\textrm{p2}^\textrm{p1} V_g dp =   \Delta H_\textrm{2} - \int_\textrm{p1}^\textrm{p2} (V_g - V_s) dp  \tag{5}$$
in accordance with Hess' law (and ignoring a smaller contribution due to the thermal expansion coefficient).
Now if we bring $p_1$ and $p_2$ arbitrarily close (but not equal) to the triple point pressure then the terms $\int_\textrm{Tsub}^\textrm{Tb} C_\textrm{p,g(p1)} dT$, $\int_\textrm{Tm}^\textrm{Tb} C_\textrm{p,l(p2)} dT $, and $\int_\textrm{p1}^\textrm{p2} (V_g - V_s) dp$  become negligibly small so that
$$\Delta H_\textrm{1} \approx \Delta H_\textrm{2}  \tag{6}$$
$$\Delta H_\textrm{1} \approx  \Delta_\textrm{sub} H_\textrm{p1} \tag{7}$$
$$\Delta H_\textrm{2} \approx \Delta_\textrm{m} H_\textrm{p2} + \Delta_\textrm{b} H_\textrm{p2}  \tag{8}$$

The solid-gas equilibrium line is discontinuous with the liquid-gas equilibrium line at the triple point because of the different heat capacities, heats of vaporization and molecular volumes. You describe two different processes.

@jimchmst what's your point? I never stated that they were equal, or that there was continuity in the properties.I get the feeling you didn't read my answer, where I clarify that there are differences in Cp and show how they don't impact the final answer (demonstrating the equality).
